# Laravel Query builder Delete Item Notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, query-builder

I am trying to delete a entry from a table named **project** in Laravel 4.2 query based on a input data.

What I have done is -

```
 DB::table('project')->where('project.id', '=', Input::get('id'))->delete();
```

But the problem is, how can I know that if the data is deleted or not?

Can anypne please help?

Comment: When you use delete() function of laravel it literally delete's the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = Input::get('id');
$entryObj = ProjectModel::findorfail($id); // Assuming you have model
// It's bad practise to delete on DB:table because you won't be able to use 
//soft-deletes or observers won't trigger if you don't use models.

if($entryObj){
    if(!$entryObj->delete()){
        throw new Exception('Now we know that it failed to delete');
    }else{
         echo "100% record is deleted.";
    }
}
```

But let's say you don't care for models/observers/soft-deletes in that case

```
if(DB::table('project')->where('project.id', '=', Input::get('id'))->delete()){
   echo "successfully deleted";
}
```

Mind you it's very very very bad practise first we not testing what Input::get('id') going to have it could be elephant or a cat in there or let's say it was supposed to have userId=1 but since they wanted to mess your data they modified on client side html to say it's 50. Boom there goes data of user 50 which is disaster if you think about it.

**Forgot to mention shortcut**

If it is id then you can also use

```
ProjectModel::destroy($id); //to delete
```

Comment: Does the return value from `delete()` indicate that the operation were successful, or that data actually got deleted from the table?  MySQL can return `true` on a delete even if nothing actually got deleted.

Comment: When you use `delete()` function of laravel it literally delete's the data.

Comment: ->delete() is laravel framework feature that deletes the data and it only returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The delete statement returns a number of how many records where affected. Hence you can check if the return value is greater than zero. In your case it should be always 1 assuming the id is unique. So an if statement if equals one then delete was successfull